# Correct Postman Settings when testing file uploading in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, post, laravel-4, postman

Does anybody know what settings to configure when using Postman extension for Chrome for testing file uploading in a Laravel 4 app?

```
$file = Input::file('media');
var_dump($file);
```

Returns null.

[image: Postman settings]

Answer (score 1):

Turns out check your PHP.ini settings and restart apache and PHP.
I was testing video files which exceeded the POST and upload size limits in my configuration, hence the results.

Comment: Are there any size limits of POSTMAN itself ? can we change that? As I have already changed my php settings but postman not accepting large files.