# File upload with Laravel through REST

Tags: php, laravel, rest, api, upload

I'm trying to upload videos (i have also tried images) through a REST api in Laravel through Postman.

So far I have tried to do the simplest upload, but nothing seems to work.
I'm doing a POST request to http://localhost:8000/api/videos using the "form-data" option in PostMan and setting the "file" option so i can use the "browse" button to find a file on my PC and calling the file "file".

In the controller i'm doing this:

```
return $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

But i get the error "Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null".
I have also tried:

```
return Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

But it's the same result.

Anyone have an idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send file with postman to Laravel API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28093586/send-file-with-postman-to-laravel-api)

Answer (score 9):

Okay, I found out what was wrong.
When choosing "form-data" in PostMan, it automatically sets a header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

I just removed the header, and everything worked :)