# Could not submit form-data through postman put request

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I m using lumen api 5.6.
This is my route
 $router->PUT('collections/{collectionId}'
In postman i m calling this api like this.
[image]

and this is the body of that request 
[image]

See here i have CollectioPoints here but its failing in validation.
the data i m sending through formdata is not able to recognized in validation.

But if i send the route from put to post [$router->POST('collections/{collectionId}'], all the data i m sending through form data are recognized and i m getting correct response as below
[image]

Why this is happening. Cant i send form data through put request?
Thaank you.

Comment: try add to headers Content-Type:multipart/form-data

Comment: i tried @J.Doe its also not working

Answer (score 22):

Laravel(Lumen) cheats because html forms only support GET and POST, but it does understand a real PUT/PATCH request.

In Postman You should send POST and set _method to PUT (same as sending forms) to make your data and files visible

```
 _method = "PUT"
```

Or

If you don't have any file only have data then you can write you parameter in choose below option in Postman

```
 x-www-form-urlencode
```

Or

You want use PUT method for send Data with  **form-Data** option you should use stuff like this https://gist.github.com/devmycloud/df28012101fbc55d8de1737762b70348

Answer (score 7):

Example

Headers: Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

_method = "PUT"

an your controller

```
return $request->file('avatar');
```

image example

[image]

Comment: where exactly i must put (_method = "PUT")??